# Generate anonymous ids in JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

The task is to extract customer and order data from a sensitive system. Data is stored in a MySQL database.

A customer can be associated with many orders. A simple LEFT JOIN gives me exactly what I require:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| customer_id | order_id | order_quantity | order_value |
---------------------------------------------------------
|      1      |    100   |       3        |    100.00   |
|      1      |    105   |      12        |    400.00   |
|      2      |    103   |       2        |     75.00   |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

However, in the generated extract, I'm not allowed to reveal the `customer_id` nor the `order_id`. Instead, these ids need to be replaced by random, anonymized identifiers generated at the time of data export.

The relationship between customers and their orders still needs to be maintained in the resulting, extracted data export.

Desired outcome:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| anon_customer_id | anon_order_id | order_quantity | order_value |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|         xyz      |      abc123   |       3        |    100.00   |
|         xyz      |      def567   |      12        |    400.00   |
|         pqr      |      hij890   |       2        |     75.00   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to generate `anon_customer_id` and `anon_order_id` as part of the `SELECT` I'm running to build the data result?

Comment: If it just about not using the real IDs, you can simply use some big number you extract the real ID from, e.g. `select 963542187 - customer_id as anon_customer_id ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using MySQL's native encryption methods like `SHA1` or `SHA2` and make a VIEW which you query and join with. 
I've choosen to use SHA 512 because it has a very low probability different data could generate the same hash.

```
CREATE VIEW Table1_VIEW AS (
   SELECT 
      <table>.*
    , SHA2(<table>.customer_id, 512) AS anon_customer_id
    , SHA2(<table>.order_id, 512) AS anon_order_id
   FROM 
    <table>
 )
```

**Query and result**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 Table1_VIEW

| customer_id | order_id | order_quantity | order_value | anon_customer_id                                                                                                                 | anon_order_id                                                                                                                    |
| ----------- | -------- | -------------- | ----------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1           | 100      | 3              | 100         | 4dff4ea340f0a823f15d3f4f01ab62eae0e5da579ccb851f8db9dfe84c58b2b37b89903a740e1ee172da793a6e79d560e5f7f9bd058a12a280433ed6fa46510a | 643c30f73a3017050b287794fc8c5bb9ab06b9ce38a1fc58df402a8b66ff58f69bf0a606ae17585352a0306f0e9752de8c5c064aed7003f52808b43ff992a603 |
| 1           | 105      | 12             | 400         | 4dff4ea340f0a823f15d3f4f01ab62eae0e5da579ccb851f8db9dfe84c58b2b37b89903a740e1ee172da793a6e79d560e5f7f9bd058a12a280433ed6fa46510a | 03d25c7071bce10d6b462d53854b969d9f61b982e3aee8771bdcca1ecb70495574e6929042f52e859ee9a253b58f776514180ff16e1338f5505e86c7ff328f72 |
| 2           | 103      | 2              | 75          | 40b244112641dd78dd4f93b6c9190dd46e0099194d5a44257b7efad6ef9ff4683da1eda0244448cb343aa688f5d3efd7314dafe580ac0bcbf115aeca9e8dc114 | 947de04bfae0bf062a66fc055d4c284c9779793d9bd58833ee7549fde1ff1effaf7aefdbc6c90ed0ac86c0acc82329e7c057d900c28ea7ed4724486f717ee38d |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbH4AvRchbN9zYDq1fsF37/0)

**p.s You can also directly use `SHA2()` directly in a `JOIN` offcource.**

**Example Query**

```
SELECT 
      table11.*
    , SHA2(table11.customer_id, 512) AS anon_customer_id
    , SHA2(table11.order_id, 512) AS anon_order_id 
FROM 
 Table1 table11
LEFT JOIN
 Table1 table12
ON
 table11.customer_id = table12.customer_id
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbH4AvRchbN9zYDq1fsF37/2)

**MYSQL 5.7+ only**

If you have atleast MySQL 5.7+ you have a even better option. 
 Which is [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  `customer_id` INTEGER,
  `order_id` INTEGER,
  `order_quantity` INTEGER,
  `order_value` INTEGER,
  anon_customer_id VARCHAR(255) AS ( SHA2(Table1.customer_id, 512) ) VIRTUAL,
  anon_order_id VARCHAR(255) AS ( SHA2(Table1.order_id, 512) ) VIRTUAL
);
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbH4AvRchbN9zYDq1fsF37/0)

**Edit because of the comment from Louis**

> my point was that someone will be able to extract the sensitive
>   customer id after it's hashed. Simply by calculating hashes of all
>   possible or likely customer id and seeing which is the same. If the
>   customer ID is not an increasing number with predictable range but
>   some randomly assigned very large number or indeed a long random
>   string it might be better

This is very true what you can do is add more entropy to the hash so the real id arn't that easy to bruteforce annymore. 
In this case you add atleast 52 characters (datetime(6) and the reverse one) as entropy that should be more then enough to protect against bruteforces for (some) years to come.

```
CREATE VIEW Table1_VIEW_more_entropy AS (
   SELECT 
      Table1.*
    , SHA2(CONCAT_WS(':', Table1.id, Table1.date_created, REVERSE(Table1.date_created), Table1.customer_id), 512)
    , SHA2(CONCAT_WS(':', Table1.id, Table1.date_created, REVERSE(Table1.date_created), Table1.order_id), 512)   
   FROM 
    Table1
 );
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbH4AvRchbN9zYDq1fsF37/3)

Comment: Super answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It would be quite easy to reveal the customer_id back from a hash.  Especially if you are hashing something as simple as a order number of custormer number.  

Those numbers would presumably have a reasonable easy to predict range.  So your customer_id ranges between say 1 and 1000000.  It would be trivial to work back on this by simply hashing all possble values of customer_id in a table.  You can then match them to to the anon_customer_id and in such a way reveal the customer_id.

Comment: @Raymond my point was that someone will be able to extract the sensitive customer id after it's hashed. Simply by calculating hashes of all possible or likely customer id and seeing which is the same.  If the customer ID is not an increasing number with predictable range but some randomly assigned very large number or indeed a long random string it might be better.

Comment: @Louis o yes offcource i wasnt reading your comment very sharply yesterday it seams blame it on the time.. Also i dont consider a customer id to be (really) sensitive information well it can leak information how many customers you have if you use a auto_increment.. Same goes for the orders which in mine opinion is more sensitive if others know the amount of orders you do in a year for example

Comment: I have a similar question and have thought of hashing as well, but given the ids are numeric in a predictiable range it means they will easily be revealed.  Hashing does not reveal the id directly but it does not really protect them from attack.

Comment: *"
I have a similar question and have thought of hashing as well, but given the ids are numeric in a predictiable range it means they will easily be revealed. Hashing does not reveal the id directly but it does not really protect them from attack."* add in more [entropy?](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbH4AvRchbN9zYDq1fsF37/3)  @Louis

Answer (score 0):

You could use any hash function, for example, MD5:

```
SELECT MD5(customer_id) AS anon_customer_id FROM customers;
```

But be aware though, MD5 is not very secure: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure